# Общая переменная для нескольких List

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
var FirstList = new List<FirstListType>();
var SecondList = new List<SecondListType>();
int a = 5;
dynamic Array;
if(a > 4)
    Array = FirstList;
else if(a < 5)
    Array = SecondList;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, синтаксис, как мне объявить переменную `Array`, не используя `dynamic`?

Comment: Половина кода исчезает, использую <pre><code> </code></pre>, что не так?

Comment: Не использовать pre и code ибо используются пробелы для форматирования..... поэтому просто использовать горячие клавиши или тулсы сверху на панели

Comment: А какой резон делать из типизированного списка массив?

Comment: @Bulson `Array` название переменной, а не тип

Comment: Тогда укажите тип этой переменной, иначе не понятно, что еще можно придумать кроме `dynamic`, если тип неизвестен!

Comment: @Bulson, так в этом то и мой вопрос, могу ли как-нибудь по-другому объявить переменную `Array` присвоив ей тип, который будет поддерживать любой тип `List<>`?

Comment: В ответах посоветовали использовать `IList`, что пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `IList` без параметров из пространства `System.Collections;`